# How to delete an array of pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am trying to get rid of memory leaks in my code but eeverytime I try to dereference the pointers, it gives an error.

The code is as follows:

exp[] is declared as follows in the abstract class Expression with concrete subclasses: Binary, Constant and Log as follows: static Expression* exp[]; which is then set to NULL in the Expression source file:
 Expression* Expression::exp[]= {NULL};

When I comment out delete b, delete l and delete co, the program runs fine but I suspect it leaves a memory leak

```
 int main(void)
    {

        char userInput='j';

        while (userInput != 'q' && userInput != 'Q')
        {       
        cout <<endl<<"Menu:" << endl<<"r - Reset the PC"<<endl<<"x - Enter a new value for register x"<<endl<<"y - Enter a new value for register y"<<endl<<"z - Enter a new value for register x"<<endl<<"s - Step by step execution"<<endl<<"e - Complete execution"<<endl<<"d - Display expressions"<<endl<<"q - Quit"<<endl;
            cin >> userInput;

            //Reset condition
            if (userInput == 'r' || userInput == 'R') 
            {
                debugPos=0;
                //Opening file and reading it line by line
                ifstream test("program.txt");
                string line;
                while (getline(test, line))
                {
                    //Removing spaces from the string
                    std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), ' ');
                    //Check if it is a log type statement and create an object of Log if it is
                    if(line[2]=='l' || line[2]=='L')
                    {
                        Log *l = new Log(line); 
                        Expression::exp[Expression::count]= l;
                        Expression::count++;
                        delete l;

                    }

                    //Check if it is a binary type statement and create an object of Binary if it is
                    else if(line[2]=='x' || line[2]=='y' || line[2]=='z' || line[2]=='X' || line[2]=='Y' || line[2]=='Z')
                    {
                        Binary *b = new Binary(line); 
                        Expression::exp[Expression::count]= b;
                        Expression::count++;
                        delete b;

                    }
                    //Else create an object of Constant type
                    else
                    {
                        Constant *co = new Constant(line); 
                        Expression::exp[Expression::count]= co;
                        Expression::count++;
                        delete co;

                    }

                }
                test.close();

                cout<<endl<<"The expressions are read from the file"<<endl;

            }


            //Complete execution
            else if (userInput == 'e' || userInput == 'E')
            {
                Expression::nExecute();
                cout<<endl<<"Value of X: "<<Expression::X<<endl<<"Value of Y: "<<Expression::Y<<endl<<"Value of Z: "<<Expression::Z<<endl;
            }


            //Quit condition
            else if (userInput == 'q' || userInput == 'Q')
            {
                cout<<endl<<"Thanks for using the calculator"<<endl;
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                cout<<endl<<"Choose from the menu please"<<endl;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Also, in the reset condition, I am trying to reset the pointers to NULL so I can start reading new expressions from the file but I am not able to set the array to point to NULL

Comment: If you're sure you need pointers, use smart pointers.

Comment: @chris Or, "if you're sure you need pointers, use `vector`". :P

Comment: Look up the functions `toupper` and `tolower` so you don't have to compare letters twice.

Comment: What do you mean smart pointers? Can't I just delete the pointer b,l and co like I did in the code? What's wrong with that?

Comment: You can use more than one line with a `cout` statement!

Comment: You don't need to `new`. Just declare a local variable. No pointer.

Comment: I highly recommend investing in the `switch` statement, much easier to use for this kind of assignment.

Comment: @user3000837: No, you can't just delete memory like you do in that code, because you're still using it, and end up with use-after-free bugs (formally known as undefined behavior).

Comment: @Alf: While that would be equivalent to the code shown, it would be equally *wrong*, leading to use of a dangling pointer, and therefore is not a useful suggestion.

Comment: @H2CO3, Well, it's an array of pointers, not a pointer used as an array.

Comment: In addition to use-after-free, you're overrunning the bounds of `Expression::exp`, which is created with a size of `1` (determined by the initializer)

Comment: @user3000837, Smart pointers will manage the memory for you so you don't have to delete it yourself and run into these problems like memory leaks and undefined behaviour.

Comment: @BenVoigt : How do I initialize the array so all of them point to NULL? I was trying to figure that out

Comment: @user3000837: You did make them all point to NULL.  But you didn't specify a size, so the compiler inferred it from the number of initializers.  Only one initializer, therefore you have `Expression* Expression::exp[1] = { 0 };` (after macro expansion and length inference)

Comment: I initialized it without a size because before I do a reset, I do not know how many elements will be there in the array. That is why I tried to create the array dynamically

Comment: @BenVoigt I have tried all the edits, but the original one works best for me when I comment out the delete statements. Can I just delete the array exp[] when I quit? Will this get rid of the memory leak?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf : I tried creating the objects statically, but the line argument I pass to the constructor doesn't set the expString of the object. How do I initialize the object when it is created in a static way?

Comment: Unless you make the array larger, your program will have undefined behavior as soon as you add a second pointer.  If you make the array larger, and `Expression::~Expression` is a virtual destructor, then you can loop through the array and delete each pointer.  `delete[] exp` will not do that.

Comment: You probably should start over with a good book, since you seem to be programming based on wishful thinking instead of learning how things behave and what recommended approaches are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better:

```
Expression::exp.emplace_back(make_unique<Log>(line));
                                              //  ^^ new Log(line) is hidden inside here
```

and so on, with

```
std::vector<unique_ptr<Expression>> exp;
```

Then the memory will be freed when the items are removed from the vector.  And it is exception-safe.

`Expression::count` will no longer be needed, since you can write `Expression::exp.size()`

Answer (score 3):

You get errors because of this

```
Constant *co = new Constant(line); 
Expression::exp[Expression::count]= co;
Expression::count++;
delete co;
```

You allocate memory, place the pointer to that memory location in an array, then release that memory - therefore next time you try to dereference the pointer stored in your array you are accessing freed memory. If you need them to persist, delete them only after you have finished.

Comment: But I am putting them in the array and after I am done using them, Can't I just say delete[] exp. This should free the memory, right?

Comment: The problem is that delete[] will free the memory allocated for the array, but your array contains pointers to other allocated memory. Once you delete the pointers to the objects you create, you are not able to access them again through that pointer. They become dangling pointers. In your case I see no advantage to using pointers anyway. As others have suggested, consider using `vector<Constant>` or `vector<Log>` etc. If you MUST have pointers then use some type of smart pointer as the other answer suggests.

Comment: It seems that you have a misunderstanding of the difference between deleting the array itself and the freeing of the memory you are allocating to your pointers with `new` calls. Deleting an array of pointers will just delete the ARRAY, it will not free the memory that each pointer in the array is pointing to. That would then be a memory leak if you forgot to free each pointer. Currently you are doing the opposite - you are freeing the memory after adding the pointer to the array so you will most likely get segfaults when trying to dereference those pointers later.